# Catching Data from uSCXML?

Tags: c#, lua, scxml

I have setup a little C# console app and can run the interpreter on scxml files and it appears to run just fine. Unfortunately there is very little in terms of examples for using uSCXML.

I embedded the interpreter in my app for runtime use, so all the questions refer to catching the data from uSCXML through the C# code.

Here are my questions:
1)  How do I receive events from a running scxml? ( for example < send event="event1" /> )
2) Using Lua as my DataModel how do I grab a variable and its expression/data from the scxml?

Thank you very much for any help

Answer (score 0):

uSCXML principal developer here. Post an issue on github and I will a) provide an example and b) update this answer to explain it. The way to do it would be a custom `IO processor` or registering an `InterpreterMonitor` and overriding `beforeEvent`, however, this callback is for events processed by the interpreter, not sent from it. You could send to yourself and ignore it though.

As to the second question, you can just send the respective data as an event (preferred) or get the datamodel from the interpreter's `ActionLanguage` and perform `evalAsData(expr)`.

Again, post an issue on github where I will actually be seeing these questions.